# Linked server in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

we have two servers one in local (windows server 2003) and one in godaddy(windows server 2008), installed sql server 2005 in both the servers and created linked servers in both the servers.

we have enabled trigger in godaddy server for one **sampletbl** table, whenever we are trying to insert the data from godaddy database to local database using the trigger enabled, then we are facing the below error.

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "211_TEST" returned message "No transaction is active.".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure 36to211, Line 8
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "211_TEST" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Trigger code is as follows :

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[36to211] on [dbo].[SampleTbl]
FOR INSERT
as
Declare @a int;
Declare @b int;
Declare @c int;
select @a=TETS_DET,@b=TEST_DET2,@c=TEST_DET3 from SampleTbl
insert into [211_TEST].[MAPBULLION].[dbo].[TEST1]
(TETS_DET,TEST_DET2,TEST_DET3)
values
(@a,@b,@c)
```

here [211_TEST] is the linked server name, MAPBULLION is the database in local server and TEST1 is the table name in local server.

Checked all the MSDTC settings and they are as per the desire

Please provide the solution.

This is the query that we are trying to execute to insert the data from godaddy server to local server:

```
insert into sampletbl (TETS_DET, TEST_DET2, TEST_DET3)
VALUES ('5', '6', '7')
```

Comment: That is going to be very unreliable (as yuo can see). You should use your trigger to insert into a log table on the GoDaddy server then load in rgaulr batches (say every five minutes) copy it over. Or you can use log shipping or replication which are 'native' ways of keeping databases synchronised. For your particular issue, it's likely that the insert occurring on the table is inside a transaction, so it is trying to enlist the linked server in the transactions and it can't.

Answer (score 0):

First hit on google for "sql server distributed transaction linked server"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/523116d4-4c8e-43a8-abf4-e705ffaa68c8/distributed-transactions-fail-on-linked-server?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Says something about it being a known issue ...